# How to use Playwright's addScriptTag to import and test a js library

Tags: javascript, browser, module, playwright

This should be a very simple problem, so its very likely I'm overlooking something.

I'm trying to test a JS library module within the browser through Playwright. This setup includes three files:

1. The library file (src/index.js)

```js
export default function randomFn() {
 let a = 1

 return a + 2
}
```

2. A wrapper for the library file to include the bind to browser's window object (src/index_browser.js)

```js
import randomFn from './index.js'

window.randomFn2 = randomFn
```

3. The playwright test file (tests/index.spec.js)

```js
 import path from 'path';
 import { expect, test as it } from '@playwright/test';

 const { describe } = it;

 const moduleFile = path.resolve(__dirname,"..","src", 'index_browser.js');

 describe('Example', () => {
   it('should test', async ({ page }) => {

     await page.addScriptTag({
       path: moduleFile,
       type: "module"
     })

     const result = await page.evaluate(
       () => {
         return randomFn2()
       },
       [],
     );

    console.log(result)
   });
 });
```

When running this code, the evaluate function does not find the randomFn function (it remains undefined).

If I remove the import within the wrapper function, and just embed the randomFn function like this:

```js
export default function randomFn() {
  let a = 1

  return a + 2
}

window.randomFn2 = randomFn
```

Everything works as expected. Is there something im missing that is causing this issue?

I've included a [sample project](https://github.com/jdalrymple/playwright-test-example) to look at the code directly.

[Example](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/blob/main/tests/page/page-add-script-tag.spec.ts#L45) from playwright tests

Related Questions/Answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61734174/1812936
- [How to use code from script with type=module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49338193/how-to-use-code-from-script-with-type-module)

Comment: What's the point of using an E2E/integration/browser test here? Seems like this circumvents the purpose of Playwright, testing a webpage in a holistic, integrated manner, not unit testing a single function. I would simply import the module and use a plain Jest test to assert `expect(randomFn()).toBe(3)`, skipping browser automation entirely. You may have oversimplified and demotivated the use case.

Comment: The simplification is satisfactory for my question. The focus of the question isnt for the testing specifically, but to figure out the behaviour of playwright in this scenario. Sorry for the confusion. The real use case is for a more complex library, to test the libraries function within a browser environment to ensure things work as expected. However the problem is the same. Creating a rudimentary example that recreated the issue is what i did instead to focus on the problem at hand.

Comment: I figured as much, but just confirming that that's the case. I see what you're doing based on your response. `import randomFn from './index.js'` seems like it won't work because there's no server hosting `index.js`, right? The web browser would have to be able to read that from the local file system. Can you confirm the error your browser gives as something like `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "./index.js". Invalid relative url or base scheme isn't hierarchical. at addScriptContent (eval at evaluate (:201:30)`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will be a satisfactory answer, but I'm also not totally clear what your actual use case is. I'll leave it in the hopes that it'll be enough for you to diagnose the issue and come up with a solution that fits your use case (or I'll come up with a cleaner solution/explanation later or update if more context becomes available).

The problem seems to be that `./index.js` points to a file on disk that isn't being served, so you should see an error like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "./index.js".
Invalid relative url or base scheme isn't hierarchical.
at addScriptContent (eval at evaluate (:201:30) ...
```

A workaround is to serve the script from a known location [with CORS enabled, like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632834/6243352):

```bash
npm install http-server -g
http-server -p 8000 --cors  # run inside project root
```

Then use a URL that points to the server:

```js
import randomFn from 'http://localhost:8000/src/index.js'

window.randomFn2 = randomFn
```

Now the import will succeed.

I assume you want the wrapper so you can test files without having to modify them, so hopefully it'll be a feasible move to modify the wrapper code's import path. You can use [Playwright's config](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-webserver) to manage starting and killing the server.

A second-order workaround if you don't want to hardcode URLs into your wrapper module is to inject the URL from the test script. This could be accomplished by reading the module file as a string, subbing the appropriate URL into the string and using the `content` key in your `addScriptTag` call rather than `path`. This is pretty ugly. An improvement may be to apply the same technique to append `window.randomFn2 = randomFn` onto an in-memory string containing your module under test and drop the wrapper module entirely. This avoids running a server for the price of a minor hack.

Otherwise, since you're potentially running a server at this point, maybe you can simply serve a simple HTML file as the wrapper to link in all of the relevant modules you want to test. Navigate to that server rather than using `addScriptTag`. This feels the least hacky among the options here--no CORS necessary, URLs don't need to be modified and the tests never need to inject scripts or manipulate strings.

Comment: You may be right, that i also need to serve the other file for it to be visible. Ill test it out and follow up!

Comment: Thanks, curious to hear how it goes. FYI, the DV is part of an ongoing targeted revenge DV campaign against my Playwright answers, so don't let that influence you unduly. There's possibly a better answer, but this does work.